# Did the little girls feed mice to walkers in The Walking Dead (season 4)?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Who fed mice to the walkers outside prison in Walking Dead season 4? I am assuming it was the little girls?

Comment: I've marked this to close. You appear to have asked two different questions.

Comment: @GoCodes neither of these questions is bad by themselves but please limit yourself to one question per post; you can edit your question and it will be flagged to review and reopening.

Comment: Both questions are pretty much dupes anyways. Re: David & Karen: [In The Walking Dead, Did Carol lie to Rick and Tyrese about killing Karen?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/72527/5184). Re: the mice: [What is wrong with Lizzie (the young blonde girl)?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53084/5184)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the beginning of the season, the Prison was a safe haven for all, but minor threats from the inside put the whole group at risk. One of these minor threats came from Lizzie. Not comprehending that the walkers are dangerous, the tween was naming and “playing” with the zombies at the prison fence. While that initially seemed innocent and like a coping mechanism, things escalated when someone began feeding rats to the walkers, making them rowdy enough to start breaking down the fences.

*Walking Dead* viewers initially speculated that Lizzie was behind the act, but it wasn’t confirmed until episode 14. In the scene from the beginning of *The Grove*:

> Carol’s frightened to
>  discover that Lizzie is outside playing with a walker. Running outside
>  to get Lizzie away from the zombie, Carol’s shocked to find Lizzie
>  trying to protect it. But that doesn’t stop her from killing the
>  walker.

And then a little later:

> Carol and Tyreese come to a conclusion that they don’t need to go to
>  Terminus – for now. But their home is not completely safe. Stationed
>  near the train tracks, Lizzie heads back to feed a stuck walker. And
>  when Mika follows her, all hell breaks loose. **Mika discovers Lizzie
>  feeding a rat to a walker, and when Mika tells her to stop playing
>  pretend with the zombies, Lizzie completely snaps.**

And even later in the same episode:

> Later that night, Carol comes clean to Tyreese about killing Karen and
>  David. “I had to stop the illness from breaking out,” she explains,
>  sliding her gun to him. “I had to stop other people from dying … It
>  wasn’t Lizzie. It wasn’t a stranger. Tyreese, it was me. Do what you
>  have to do.”

**Briefly, Lizzie feed rats to the walker, and Carol kills Karen and David.**

Here's the official [source](http://www.ibtimes.com/walking-dead-season-4-spoilers-what-happened-lizzie-episode-14-grove-karens-killer-confirmed-two) an [an article](http://www.ibtimes.com/walking-dead-season-4-spoilers-lizzies-chilling-episode-14-drama-top-8-most-disturbing-lizzie-scenes) which is also relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It was the elder of the little girls(Lizzie) who feeds rats and it was Carol who burns the bodies so that others will not get infected

Comment: how did the flu start in prison?

Comment: this is wrong LOL Carol is a good answer but not the rat feeder !

Comment: Lizzie does feed the zombies, she later on kills her own sister

Comment: @Cherubel Sorry